# Theorem 2.26 Apostol's Analytic Number Theory

Tags: number-theory

The below texts are from the book Introduction to Analytic Number Theory by Apostol:

[image]

[image]

I think the proof of the above theorem is not correct, because the identity $\log n = \log d + \log(n/d) $ will be summed over $d$ for the-number-of-divisors times (say $N$), so we may multiply r.h.s. by $N^{-1}$ to make them correct. I mean that it makes a difference (i.e. multiplied by $N$) when we sum over $d$. Am I right?

Comment: Wow, no, not at all correct.  Just write out the sums without summation notation for some reasonably small $n$ like $n=4$ (which has 3 divisors), and you'll see that this multiplying by $N^{-1}$ idea is completely nonsensical.

Answer (score 4):

No, the proof in Tom Apostol's book (not Apostle, by the way) is correct. The first sum with $\log(n)$ is over all positive divisors of $n$. Now for each divisor $d\mid n$ we just rewrite $\log(n)=\log(d)+\log(n/d)$. So we do not change the first sum by this. Hence the result.

Comment: @Liebe Oh, sorry. It was perfectly clear to me. Why is it not a solution ? I apologize.

Comment: I think the answer is that the decomposition $\log(n)=\log(d)+\log(n/d)$ will not effect the sum since the 'extra' terms cancel out.

Comment: Take an example: $n=pq$ with primes $p.q$. So $d=1,p,q,pq$. Then we have $\sum_{d\mid n}\log(n)=\log(1)+\log(p)+\log(q)+\log(pq)$. Now rewrite, for each $d$, $\log(n)=\log(d)+\log(n/d)$. Then the sum is $(\log(1)+\log(n))+(\log(p)+\log(n/p))+(\log(q)+\log(n/q))+((\log(n)+\log(n/n))$. This gives exactly the same because $\log(n/d)=\log(n)-\log(d)$.

Comment: @Liebe If you say "canceling out", then this is just $\log(n/d)=\log(n)-\log(d)$, the minus sign giving rise to "canceling". But note, this is just the formula $\log(n)=\log(d)+\log(n/d)$, nothing more. I do not think the downvote is fair, but anyway, I just want to help you.